# optimize angularjs search filter and trigger html tab even by clicking on link

Tags: html, angularjs, search, filter

I hope someone can help me with these two problems.
They are part of the same work but different from each other.

I am using angularjs to filter through a list that is quiete big (more than 1000 elements) but it's very slow. I was wondering if there's a way to optimize this.

Here's the code

```
<div class="test">

<table class="table table-hover" >
<tbody>

<tr  ng-repeat="test in tests| filter:query">
<td>

<a href="#"><div id="delete">D<br />E<br />L<br /></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="edit">E<br />D<br />I<br />T</div></a>

<p     ng-show="test.id">ID:<b>{{test.id}}</b></p>
<span  ng-repeat="name in test.names" ng-show="test.names">Company: <b>{{name}}</b></span>
<span  ng-repeat="age in test.ages"      ng-show="test.ages">Country: <b>{{age}}</b></span>
<span  ng-repeat="course in test.courses"            ng-show="test.courses">Found: <b>{{course}}</b></span>
<span  id="output"                               ng-show="test.out1">Then: <b>{{test.out1}}{{test.out2}}{{test.out3}}{{test.out4}}</b></span>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

---

The second question is regarding "tabset" in html
I have 3 tabs and in one tab I have an edit link on each item, I want the third tab to come up when I click on the edit link of the first tab.
I searched online and understand that some js or jquery is needed but nothing has worked so far.

thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are handling such a big set of data you should use a pagination system.

Also I won't attach the entire 1k object to the scope and and use a filter in the ng-repeat but instead add just a chunk of data like 50 to the scope and every time you change the page you would change the $scope.tests with the next/previous 50 items from your 1k.

One more point, if you are using a lot of interpolation {{}} but not each of them needs a separate watcher you should consider using angular's "bindonce".

Comment: I have found a way to change the tab using javascript.
I am going to put the code here so it might help someone else in the same situation.
First of all I gave an id to each tab, then in the link of the first tab I made a call to a javascript function that triggers the change.
The name of my third tab is #ek
The id of my tabset is #tabs
The script is
    <script>
function editTab(){
 $('#tabs #ek a').click();
}
</script>

I'm calling changing to the third tab by calling editTab() in my link, like below:

<a onclick="editTab()" ><div id="edit">E<br />D<br />I<br />T</div></a>

Comment: I've found a way to change the tab using js
I'm going to put the code here,it might help someone.
First of all I gave an id to each tab, then in the link of the first tab I made a call to a javascript function that triggers the change.
The name of my third tab is #ek
The id of my tabset is #tabs
The script is
    <script>
function editTab(){
 $('#tabs #ek a').click();
}
</script>

I'm calling changing to the third tab by calling editTab() in my link, like below:

<a onclick="editTab()" ><div id="edit">E<br />D<br />I<br />T</div></a>

any other way to make it faster without pagination?

Comment: This is far from being anything related to Angular :) You shouldn't have global functions and also not using onclick on elements. You HTML components should be directive, your functions should be methods attached to a scope and onclick should be ng-click.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with js and front end development reason why I'm trying to make stuff work. Can you tell me how I would set the function as private? I have used ng-clic="editTab()" but it doesn't work.
what's the correct way of doing this?

Comment: ng-click="editTab()" won't work because ng-click is an angular directive and is expective an "angular function". The structure of your "app" should be like this: 
1. the whole tabbing system should be a directive;
2. inside the directive "link" function you would have a $scope.changeTab() method (which can only be used inside the directive scope)
3. use ng-click="changeTab(1)" and trigger the code inside that method
I think it's hard to start with angular while your overall JS experience is pretty low. You should have a look at Angular's tutorials to get a better understanding of it.

Comment: Even a lot of experienced JS developers have problems getting used with "the angular way".